# WP8 Skydrive Read Folder Compiler Error

Tags: asynchronous, windows-phone-8, onedrive

```
          LiveConnectClient liveClient = new LiveConnectClient(this.session);
          LiveOperationResult operationResult =
                    await liveClient.GetAsync("folder.8c8ce076ca27823f.8C8CE076CA27823F!126");
                dynamic result = operationResult.Result;
```

This code is taken directly from the samples here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826531.aspx#reading_files_props

It is complaining in Visual Studio 2012 that Error  2   The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

How am I supposed to modify the GetAsync function when it is part of the SkyDrive API and this is the code they've given to me to complete the operation.

I am using the most recent v5.5 of the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add async keyword to signature of your method.
Example:

```
public async void YourMethod()
{
...
  LiveConnectClient liveClient = new LiveConnectClient(this.session);
          LiveOperationResult operationResult =
                    await liveClient.GetAsync("folder.8c8ce076ca27823f.8C8CE076CA27823F!126");
                dynamic result = operationResult.Result;
...
}
```

more info here :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443%28VS.110%29.aspx
about return Task or void in section :Return types and parameters